# Typescript get specific union element with its own specific properties

Tags: typescript, generics, types, union, type-inference

I've been writing typescript code for some time.
I found out that I don't know how to achieve the result I wish.

Let's say I have a `ElementData` - I am not quiet sure about this one.

```
type ElementData<TData extends any> = TData;
```

Inside of `Element`.

```
interface Element<TName extends string, TElementData extends ElementData<any>> {
  name: TName;
  data: TElementData;
}
```

Union of `Element` is stored inside a `Container`.

```
interface Container<TElement extends Element<string, ElementData<any>>> {
  elements: TElement[];
  getElement: <TElementName extends TElement["name"]>(
    elementName: TElementName,
  ) => Element<TElementName, TElement["data"]> extends infer UElement extends Element<TElementName, any>
    ? UElement
    : never;
}
```

I belive I need to use `infer` once again somewhere but I don't know where.

```
type ElementData<TData extends any> = TData;

interface Element<TName extends string, TElementData extends ElementData<any>> {
  name: TName;
  data: TElementData;
}

interface Container<TElement extends Element<string, ElementData<any>>> {
  elements: TElement[];
  getElement: <TElementName extends TElement["name"]>(
    elementName: TElementName,
  ) => Element<TElementName, TElement["data"]> extends infer UElement extends Element<TElementName, any>
    ? UElement
    : never;
}

const container = {} as Container<Element<"one", { oneKey: 1 }> | Element<"two", { twoKey: 2 }>>;

const element = container.getElement("one");
console.log(element.name === "one");
console.log(element.name === "two"); // error
console.log(element.data.oneKey === 1); // error, should not be
console.log(element.data.twoKey === 2); // error

const element2 = container.getElement("two");
console.log(element2.name === "one"); // error
console.log(element2.name === "two");
console.log(element2.data.oneKey === 1); // error
console.log(element2.data.twoKey === 2); // error, should not be
```

I would really appriopriate any help.

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogNhAthAdsAIgQ2JgPAFSxyggA9hUATAZykxRAD4oBeKQ7TAbgCgeBLNBABOAM0wBjaPCSpgBAHKZkJclVrVgwwQHMANOxnI0RTKoooasBMYydc9JswDePKFBTKIALnZLkvO6UnL74RnKmvAC%20fIIUYpLQAMIA9miYgiIE4Wjm6tayaLia2ij6BbamDgyMtVCu7hA2ctShOcAA2gC6gVA6EMDtvtnNaP7QZBZWYaOdAESeyHNdjAAUbu4ks%20Nt2156GwCUrMztI4XA4wYzFx1zwTjLzJP5gqIiUACq7XmWtGc3WxXOg1DbuAD8X3aYKgvhQEAAbiJonwJGlNFA0elMsJWPUonRaKlsfDhLgznM0hA5gZnFAqQBpCAgXwARigUWYAB8KnJcHNgAB3FI0%20pQIUpJksqAAJg5tV4PCxGKaFzxWJwOIAdP1BrNVpT4XNDrxlSkEFq4CkdKtVbYtYtoCxnVBDdSTUr0eaIJbrbbZg6vKwXQLhcauFAAPSRkjCYQpYSelDUb2%20m12uRah6YLWM5nBtisk1RmMiePCAzUAAWKQArnBKB4UsAoAAjCBJlMWq3pgPZrUSqUF2XF6Ox8uo9EtjNoOVsDUZUk6gbtA0S8Od1M9-0XGWBlTOthu8Ml8cJzfdv0z4B7x3D0Mij1my%2093dZzi5%20FDw9QIsRsdluez4%20tu157v2g75j%20MqjqWcYJpWNb1o2KDNm2EBAA)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler than I expected.
Tiny change in `Container` `getElement` return type did the trick.
`TElement["data"]` into `Extract<TElement, { name: TElementName }>["data"]`

```
interface Container<TElement extends Element<string, ElementData<any>>> {
  elements: TElement[];
  getElement: <TElementName extends TElement["name"]>(
    elementName: TElementName,
  ) => Element<TElementName, Extract<TElement, { name: TElementName }>["data"]> extends infer UElement extends Element<
    TElementName,
    any
  >
    ? UElement
    : never;
}
```